# Py4J problems with my_class.class attribute. What is it?

Tags: java, python, py4j

I am trying to access **Java DAO** methods from Python using [Py4J](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/), and I am running into a strange problem.  I have the following `MyApplication.java` file. I can compile correctly, and it seems to sort of work from Python using [Py4J](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/):

```
import py4j.GatewayServer;

import company.common.dao.DAOFactory;
import company.sys.dao.ABCartDAO;

public class MyApplication {

  public String foo (int n) {
    ShoppingCart bar = DAOFactory.getDAO(ABCartDAO.class);
    String identifier bar.findit(n)
    return identifier;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyApplication app = new MyApplication();
    GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(app);
    server.start();
  }
}
```

I can start the server with `java MyApplication`. However, when I run the following in Python:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()                   # connect to the JVM

# Testing that it works
random = gateway.jvm.java.util.Random()   # create a java.util.Random instance
number1 = random.nextInt(10)              # call the Random.nextInt method
number2 = random.nextInt(10)
print(number1,number2)

my_application = gateway.entry_point        

my_application.foo(4)
```

Getting the random numbers works (proof that Py4J is doing its job), but the call to operation in it fails with:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-d2345f6205bf> in <module>()
----> 1 my_application.foo(4)

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
    535         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    536         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 537                 self.target_id, self.name)
    538 
    539         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling t.foo.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: company/sys/dao/ABCartDAO
        at MyApplication.foo(MyApplication.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Why?

In case it matters, I am building my java file with the following in my `pom.xml`

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.py4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>py4j</artifactId>
    <type>jar</type>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

Am I a supposed to include some additional dependencies in the compilation of my `.class` file? Is this a bug of `Py4J`? Perhaps an unsupported feature?

Comment: You have too many unrelated questions packed in here.

Comment: Thanks @Jason C - I will improve my question. My post is really about the fact that I am unable to  refer to `MyClass.class` when using  `Py4J`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of unrelated questions here. Answering the first one:

> Say I define a class called MyClass What does MyClass.class hold? is it a string? (if so, what would it be for MyClass?) Something else?

It holds a reference to a [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object, which you can use for various things, most notable getting runtime information about the class for debugging and reflection. It is also the same thing returned by the non-static method [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29):

```
Class<?> clz = MyClass.class;
Class<?> clz = new MyClass().getClass();
```

I am not completely familiar with Py4J, but you may be able to use the latter to access the `Class` of a given object instance. Note that `getClass()` is a base method of `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to get that information (and use it with Java DAOs), without relying on runtime inspection? I wonder if Py4J does not recognize the class since the reference in the code is assumed to happen in run-time.

Comment: Thanks - When I change my code to use `getClass()` it complains with: `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: @user815423426 I may have your problem backwards.

Comment: Thanks - I tried doing what you said, i.e. using `new ABCartDAO().getClass()` but now I get: `ABCartDAO is abstract; cannot be instantiated`. That's probably what I call bad luck!

Comment: @user815423426 Yeah; that wouldn't work. I'm reading Py4J docs looking for clues about why a class in the classpath can't be found, but haven't found anything yet. I'll let you know if I do. Are you *positive* the Java code compiles, and that all relevant `.class` files are present? Are you packaging this in a JAR? If so, does the JAR actually contain `ABCartDAO` and is the JAR on the JVM's class path? What happens if you try and test your code with pure Java, without going through Python?

Comment: Thanks @Jason! I think the JAR that I build may not contain `ABCCartDAO`. Is it supposed to? I am using IDEA to build it with `make` - What should my `pom.xml` say if I want to include `ABCartDAO` in it? I can certainly compile with no errors. The compilation generates a `.class` file.

Comment: The JAR *must* contain `ABCartDAO` (and all other referenced classes) if that class is to be referenced.

Comment: That's probably it! I will look up online how I can ask IDEA to include. If you have any thoughts (e.g. it's something that I need to specify in my `pom.xml` etc.) let me know

Comment: @user815423426 I actually don't use maven, I use ant for builds so I can't give you a good answer on that one without looking it up.

Comment: Thanks - By the way, would it suffice to have a different JAR containing `ABCartDAO` in `CLASSPATH` when running `java MyApplication` ?

Comment: @user815423426 Yes; as long as its in your classpath that will work fine.

Comment: Just to add to the comments, it seems from the stack trace that Py4J is able to call your method and the exception occurs while in the method (this is thus not related to py4j). You may better test the code by calling method foo() from the main() method. Does it work?